# Display images from a chosen array based on radio button selection?

Tags: javascript, arrays, if-statement, radio-button

- So I want to display a different array of images for a give radio button selection using javascript but can't get the code to run. A solution using jquery would also work.

  ```
  <script language="javascript">


  var surffamous = new Array;
  surffamous[0] = "teahupoo.jpg"
  surffamous[1] = "blacks.jpg"
  surffamous[2] = "supertubes.jpg"
  surffamous[3] = "pipeline.jpg"

  var surfsocal = new Array;
  surfsocal[0] = "lajolla.jpg"
  surfsocal[1] = "oceanside.jpg"
  surfsocal[2] = "delmar.jpg"
  surfsocal[3] = "cardiff.jpg"

  var surfcentralcal = new Array;
  surfcentralcal[0] = "rincon.jpg"
  surfcentralcal[1] = "leocarillo.jpg"
  surfcentralcal[2] = "elcapitan.jpg"
  surfcentralcal[3] = "hollister.jpg"
  ```

  ```
  <form style="color: #2D5059">
  <p>Where would you like to explore?</p< <br> <br>
  <input type="radio" name="spot" id="socal" value="southern">Southern California
  <input type="radio" name="spot" id="central" value="central">Central California
  <input type="radio" name="spot" id="famous" value="famous">Famous Spots
  </form>


  <script language="javascript">
  function check() {
  for(i=0; i<4; i++){
  if(document.getElementById('socal').checked) {
  document.write('<img src="'+  surfsocal[i] +'"/> ' + '</a>');
  }
  else if(document.getElementById('central').checked) {
  document.write('<img src="'+  surfcentralcal[i] +'"/> ' + '</a>');
  }
  else if(document.getElementById('famous').checked) {
  document.write('<img src="'+  surffamous[i] +'"/> ' + '</a>');
  }
  }
  </script>
  ```

Comment: Should spend some more time formatting the code here.  Also what's the issue/question?

Comment: Yeah sorry first time asking question on here so the initial formatting through me. Should look better now! I just want to display an array based on a radio button selection (with three options).

Comment: Do you want the images to load when you click a radio or on the press of a button?

Comment: at the click of the radio preferably, although adding a button would not be out of the question.

Answer (score 1):

**Your code doesn't run because it throws an error:** you are missing the `}` token to 'close' the check function.

**Try this, I made some changes:**

```css
#images img {
    margin: 1em;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<form style="color: #2D5059">
    <p>Where would you like to explore?</p>

    <input type="radio" name="spot" id="socal" value="southern">
    <label for="socal">Southern California</label>

    <input type="radio" name="spot" id="central" value="central">
    <label for="central">Central California</label>

    <input type="radio" name="spot" id="famous" value="famous">
    <label for="famous">Famous Spots</label>

</form>
<br>
<div id="images"></div>

<script>
// Find the images div and all of the radio buttons
var images = document.getElementById('images'),
    radioButtons = document.getElementsByName('spot');

// Use [] instead of new Array()
var surffamous = [];
surffamous[0] = "teahupoo.jpg"
surffamous[1] = "blacks.jpg"
surffamous[2] = "supertubes.jpg"
surffamous[3] = "pipeline.jpg"

var surfsocal = [];
surfsocal[0] = "lajolla.jpg"
surfsocal[1] = "oceanside.jpg"
surfsocal[2] = "delmar.jpg"
surfsocal[3] = "cardiff.jpg"

var surfcentralcal = [];
surfcentralcal[0] = "rincon.jpg"
surfcentralcal[1] = "leocarillo.jpg"
surfcentralcal[2] = "elcapitan.jpg"
surfcentralcal[3] = "hollister.jpg"

function check() {
    var image,
        fragment = document.createDocumentFragment();
    for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        // Don't use document.write
        image = new Image();

        // 'this' refers to the clicked radio button
        if (this.id === 'socal') {
            image.src = surfsocal[i];
        } else if (this.id === 'central') {
            image.src = surfcentralcal[i];
        } else if (this.id === 'famous') {
            image.src = surffamous[i];
        }
        // The fragment helps you minimize
        // direct DOM insertions
        fragment.appendChild(image);
    }
    images.innerHTML = '';
    images.appendChild(fragment);
}

// Attach a listener to each button, using a loop
for(var i = radioButtons.length; i--;) {
    radioButtons[i].onchange = check;
}
</script>
```

**Make sure that you include the script tag after the `images` div.**
We are basically avoiding `document.write`, attaching an `onchange` listener to each radio button, and creating an image and appending it to a div when you click a radio button (when it changes).

I also changed some stuff, like `new Array` to literal declaration `[]`, and added labels to your radio buttons, so that when you click on the text, it's as if you clicked on the button.

Hope this works for you. If not, please let me know. Good luck : )

Comment: Hey Alfonso this works but I was wondering if there is way to pad the images or space them when they appear?

Comment: Yeah, sure, you just have to add some CSS. I've updated the answer, take a look at the CSS snippet at the top, I just added a `margin` property. You can also control the width and height of the images, if you wish (remove those properties if you want them to be in their original size).

Answer (score 0):

```
function check(spot) {

    var whichArray;
    if (spot.value == "southern") {
        whichArray = surfsocal;
    }
    else if (spot.value == "central") {
        whichArray = surfcentralcal;
    }
    else if (spot.value == "famous") {
        whichArray = surffamous;
    }
    DisplayImages(whichArray);
}
function DisplayImages(images) {
    for(i=0; i<images.length; i++) {
        document.write('<img src="'+  images[i] +'"/> ');
    }
}
```

Then add onclicks to the radio buttons

```
<input type="radio" name="spot" id="socal" value="southern" onclick="check(this);">Southern California
<input type="radio" name="spot" id="central" value="central" onclick="check(this);">Central California
<input type="radio" name="spot" id="famous" value="famous" onclick="check(this);">Famous Spots
```

Didn't test, but should get you started